# Code that Worked with MultiView fails with Wizard ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, wizard, multiview

I originally created a process that occurred by transitioning between views in a multiview and it worked fine. Now, I've moved this same code into a ASP.NET Wizard and it keeps throwing an error at the second step. The error is:
Method 'System.Object AndObject(System.Object, System.Object)' has no supported translation to SQL.
Any ideas why this would occur when moving the code into the wizard? I'm sure its something stupid, but I've checked over the code 3-4 times now and it appears identical operationally.
Here is the code:
' Make sure we have the LDAP portion of the .NET Framework available.
Imports System.DirectoryServices ' Allows us to interface with LDAP.
Imports System.Data.Linq.SqlClient ' Allows us to use LINQ SQL Methods.

Partial Public Class buildit
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' ******* Grab the LDAP info. for current user.
    Dim ID As FormsIdentity = DirectCast(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)
    Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = ID.Ticket
    Dim adDirectory As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=[info],DC=[info],DC=[info],DC=[info]")
    ' We need to strip off @email.address from the ticket name, so we'll use substring to grab the first 
    ' five characters.
    Dim adTicketID As String = ticket.Name.Substring(0, 5)
    Dim adEmployeeID As String
    adEmployeeID = adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("employeeID").Value

    ' ******* Lets make sure they have signed the housing contract and the community covenant.
    Dim dbContractSigs As New pcRoomOccupantsDataContext
    Dim pcContractSigs = From p In dbContractSigs.webContractSigs _
                         Where p.people_id = adEmployeeID _
                         Select p.res_contract, p.comm_life
    If pcContractSigs.Count.Equals(0) Then
        Response.Redirect("signcontract.aspx")
    Else
        Dim cs As String = pcContractSigs.First.res_contract.ToString
        Dim cos As String = pcContractSigs.First.comm_life.ToString
        If cs = "Y" And cos = "Y" Then
            ' We don't need to do anything.
            ' We use the else statement b/c there are multiple conditions that could occur besides "N"
            ' that would cause us to redirect to the signature page, whereas there is only one valid response - "Y".
        Else
            ' Redirect the individual to our contracts page.
            Response.Redirect("signcontract.aspx")
        End If
    End If

    ' ******* Now lets find out what gender that individual is.
    Dim dbIndividual As New pcPeopleDataContext
    Dim pcIndividual = From p In dbIndividual.PEOPLEs _
                       Join d In dbIndividual.DEMOGRAPHICs On p.PEOPLE_CODE_ID Equals d.PEOPLE_CODE_ID _
                       Where p.PEOPLE_ID = adEmployeeID _
                       Select p, d
    ' Make a session variable that will carry with the user throughout the session delineating gender.
    Session("sgender") = pcIndividual.First.d.GENDER.ToString
    ' Debug Code.
    ' Put a stop at end sub to get these values.
    ' Response.Write(adEmployeeID)

End Sub
Sub LinqDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs)
    ' Lets get a list of the dorms that are available for user's gender.
    Dim pcDorms As New pcDormsDataContext
    Dim selectedDorms = (From sd In pcDorms.PBU_WEB_DORMs _
                    Where IIf(Session("sgender").ToString = "M", sd.description = "Male", sd.description = "Female") _
                    Select sd.dorm_building).Distinct()
    e.Result = selectedDorms
End Sub
Public Sub Button_ItemCommand(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    ' ******** Lets pass on the results of our query in LinqDataSource1_Selecting.
    Session("sdorm") = RTrim(e.CommandName)

    ' ******** Debug code.
    ' Response.Write(sDorm)
End Sub
Sub LinqDataSource2_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs)
    ' ******** Get a list of rooms available in the dorm for user's gender.
    Dim pcDorms As New pcDormsDataContext
    Dim selectedDorm = (From sd In pcDorms.PBU_WEB_DORMs _
                        Where IIf(Session("sgender").ToString = "M", sd.description = "Male", sd.description = "Female") _
                        And sd.dorm_building = CStr(Session("sdorm")) _
                        Select sd.dorm_room)
    e.Result = selectedDorm
End Sub
Public Sub Button2_ItemCommand(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    ' ******** Lets pass on the results of our query in LinqDataSource2_Selecting.
    Session("sroom") = RTrim(e.CommandName)
End Sub
Sub LinqDataSource3_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs)
    ' ******** Grabs the individuals currently listed as residing in this room and displays them. Note the use of SqlMethods.Like 
    ' for dorm_building, this is due to legacy issues where dorms sometimes have leading or trailing blank spaces. We could have 
    ' also used Trim.
    Dim pcOccupants As New pcRoomOccupantsDataContext
    Dim roomOccupants = (From ro In pcOccupants.webResidents _
                       Where SqlMethods.Like(ro.dorm_building, "%" & CStr(Session("sdorm")) & "%") _
                        And ro.dorm_room = CStr(Session("sroom")) _
                      Select ro.person_name)
    e.Result = roomOccupants

    ' ******** Debug code.
    'Response.Write(CStr(Session("sdorm")))
    'Response.Write(CStr(Session("sroom")))
End Sub
Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ' ******** Reserve the room for a student.
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My old code looked like this:

```
Dim selectedDorm = (From sd In pcDorms.PBU_WEB_DORMs _
                            Where IIf(Session("sgender").ToString = "M", sd.description = "Male", sd.description = "Female") _
                            And sd.dorm_building = Session("sdorm").ToString _
                            Select sd.dorm_room)
```

And wasn't working (but did work when using MultiViews). I changed it to this:

```
Dim selectedDorm = (From sd In pcDorms.PBU_WEB_DORMs _
                            Where IIf(Session("sgender").ToString = "M", sd.description = "Male", sd.description = "Female") _
                            Where sd.dorm_building = Session("sdorm").ToString _
                            Select sd.dorm_room)
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell without seeing the code; there is a LINQ query that pulls some info from the DB, which is now causing an error.  But can't tell you anything without seeing code.